# Performance difference between @gen.engine and @gen.coroutine Tornado 4.4.2

Tags: asynchronous, tornado, coroutine

I have one handler method decorated with @gen.coroutine:

```
class MyHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    @gen.coroutine
    def post(self):

        ...
```

```

When I execute performance test on this API, my service is able to execute 3 or 4 requests per second maximum.

If I simply change `@gen.coroutine` to `@gen.engine` and I execute exactly the same performance test, the service is able to handle around 50 requests per second.

What is the reason for this performance difference between the two decorators ? Is my @gen.engine usage wrong ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There should not be any performance difference between the two decorators. Are you sure your application is doing the same thing in both cases? It is not equivalent to simply replace `@gen.coroutine` with `@gen.engine` on an implementation of `RequestHandler.post`. You must also add `@tornado.web.asynchronous`, which is required with `@engine` but not used with `@coroutine`.